# How to group the outprint by coincidence of 1 column

Tags: python

This is my code.
This thing searchs for a specific file names and then gives me the path

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 31-05-2022", topdown=False):
    dictionary = ["INFORME.pdf", "CARTA.pdf", "FUN ONI.pdf"]
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(dictionary[i]):
                directorio, carpeta, archivo = os.path.join(root, file).split("\\")
                print(directorio+"/"+carpeta,";", archivo)
```

and this is the outprint:

```
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2456-2022 C.A. PUNTA ARENAS ; 2456-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2488-2022 C.A. PUNTA ARENAS ; 2488-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2488-2022 C.A. PUNTA ARENAS ; 2488-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2488-2022 C.A. PUNTA ARENAS ; 2488-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2959-2022 C.A. CHILLÁN ; 2959-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2959-2022 C.A. CHILLÁN ; 2959-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2959-2022 C.A. CHILLÁN ; 2959-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/5109-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 5109-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/5109-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 5109-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/5109-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 5109-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/7939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 7939-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/7939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 7939-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/7939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 7939-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8014-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8014-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8014-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8014-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8014-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8014-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8121-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8121-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8121-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8121-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8121-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8121-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8191-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8191-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8191-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8191-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8191-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8191-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8192-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8192-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8192-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8192-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8192-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8192-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8232-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8232-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8232-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8232-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8232-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8232-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8470-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8470-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8470-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8470-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8470-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8470-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8555-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8555-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8555-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8555-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8555-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8555-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8910-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8910-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8910-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8910-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8910-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8910-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8939-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8939-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8939-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8940-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8940-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8940-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8940-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8940-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 8940-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9041-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9041-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9041-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9041-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9041-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9041-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9042-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9042-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9042-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9042-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9042-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9042-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9102-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9102-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9308-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9308-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9308-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9308-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9308-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9308-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9309-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9309-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9309-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9309-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9309-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9309-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9310-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9310-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9310-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9310-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9310-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9310-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9312-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9312-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9312-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9312-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9312-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9312-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9332-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9332-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9332-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9332-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9332-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9332-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9334-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9334-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9334-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9334-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9334-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9334-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9430-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9430-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9430-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9430-2022 CARTA.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9430-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9430-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9532-2022 C.A. TEMUCO ; 9532-2022 INFORME.pdf
```

I would like to this whit python:

```
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2456-2022 C.A. PUNTA ARENAS , 2456-2022 INFORME.pdf, 2456-2022 CARTA.pdf, 2456-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2488-2022 C.A. PUNTA ARENAS , 2488-2022 INFORME.pdf, 2488-2022 CARTA.pdf, 2488-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/2959-2022 C.A. CHILLÁN , 2959-2022 INFORME.pdf, 2959-2022 CARTA.pdf, 2959-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/5109-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 5109-2022 INFORME.pdf, 5109-2022 CARTA.pdf, 5109-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/7939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 7939-2022 INFORME.pdf, 7939-2022 CARTA.pdf, 7939-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8014-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8014-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8014-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8014-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8121-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8121-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8121-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8121-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8191-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8191-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8191-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8191-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8192-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8192-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8192-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8192-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8232-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8232-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8232-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8232-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8470-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8470-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8470-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8470-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8555-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8555-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8555-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8555-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8910-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8910-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8910-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8910-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8939-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8939-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8939-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8939-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/8940-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 8940-2022 INFORME.pdf, 8940-2022 CARTA.pdf, 8940-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9041-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9041-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9041-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9041-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9042-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9042-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9042-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9042-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9102-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9102-2022 INFORME.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9308-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9308-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9308-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9308-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9309-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9309-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9309-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9309-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9310-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9310-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9310-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9310-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9312-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9312-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9312-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9312-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9332-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9332-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9332-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9332-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9334-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9334-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9334-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9334-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9430-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9430-2022 INFORME.pdf, 9430-2022 CARTA.pdf, 9430-2022 FUN ONI.pdf
D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 01-06-2022/9532-2022 C.A. TEMUCO , 9532-2022 INFORME.pdf
```

For now i can do it using a series of excel formulas but probably is also achievable with python.

Can any1 help me with this?

Here is the excel https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUQgXdQDCs9eZLrUmI0T9OwvFA-RBBSYH7N05SZ3PSQ/edit?usp=sharing

maybe u can understand better if you ckeck my excel file

Comment: You have two lines with `C.A. PUNTA ARENAS` and `INFORME` in the desired result, but there's only one such line in the original result? (there's no match for `01-06-2022/2456-2022`)

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the directory structure you are working with? Perhaps reduce it to 2-3 folders with the right files?

Comment: thanks u guy for trying to help me!!!!. Andang Sudrajat came with answerd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you use a dictionary, something like this:

```
import os

records = dict()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("D:/Llanos/INFORMES TF 31-05-2022", topdown=False):
    dictionary = ["INFORME.pdf", "CARTA.pdf", "FUN ONI.pdf"]
    for i in range(0, 3):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(dictionary[i]):
                directorio, carpeta, archivo = os.path.join(root, file).split("\\")
                index = directorio+"/"+carpeta
                if not (index in records):
                    records[index] = list()
                records[index].append( archivo )

# print
for index in records:
    print(index, ",", (',').join(records[index]))
```